# Does the US offer a travel visa in order to travel from a US airport?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, transit-visas

I have a US tourist visa, I live in Canada, I suppose I can drive to a US airport (NewYork) and travel from there to France. Another family member is also a Canadian resident but have no US visa, I want him to come with me.

Is there a visa that the US offers for this situation ? We only need a day or 2 for the drive.

Comment: https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-619?language=en_US lays it out. You need to apply for an ESTA now before crossing a land border.

Comment: What passport does your family member have?

Comment: Note: "family member" have different meaning. Are you speaking about your children or your parents, or something more indirect like a fiance of the son of the uncle of your wife? -- In any case my recommendation: void unnecessary visa/countries: things sometime go wrong, and when they go wrong in such set-up, it will be very expensive

Comment: What nationality is your family member?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi DId you mean to type "void" or did you intend "**avoid**?

Comment: @Hilmar: Canada is not part of the Visa Waiver Program and Canadian citizens do not need ESTA.

Comment: OP mentions that the family member is also a Canadian resident, that makes me think neither are Canadian citizens.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got my answer through the link in the first comment, the wait times for getting an interview make it impossible to consider (296 days for Ottawa).

Comment: @Hilmar not only do Canadian citizens not need ESTA but they cannot get ESTA (unless they have another nationality that is eligible for ESTA).

Comment: @JonCuster someone with a US tourist visa should not apply for ESTA as ESTA is for people using the visa waiver program.  Someone with a tourist visa does not need to have the visa requirement waived.  The other family member may or may not be eligible for ESTA depending on his nationality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you guys are not Canadian citizens, since you have a US visa and are talking about getting a US visa for your family member, and Canadian citizens do not need US visas to visit the US.

If your family member has a passport from a Visa Waiver Program country, they should get an ESTA to enter the US on the Visa Waiver Program.

Otherwise, your family member should get either a C1 transit visa or a B2 visitor visa to enter the US for transit. A visitor visa can be used for transit, and since they are going to the trouble of applying for a visa anyway, they might as well apply for a visitor visa, so that it can be used for visits later, unless for some reason they are likely to be denied a visitor visa.

Comment: Note that the wait time for US visitor visas in Canada currently is more than a year. The chances for a C-1 visa are also minimal, as the transit in the U.S. is almost certainly considered unnecessary.

Comment: Why do they consider it unnecessary ? It is not like they offer lot of airports to travel from!

Comment: @xngtng does the US actually issue transit visas only to people who are unable to avoid transit in the US?  I've never heard of such a requirement.

Comment: @NotaChoice Canada is well-connected to France, I think that's what they meant. But there are absolutely no such requirements if we go by the [State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html)

Comment: @phoog No, but the itinerary must still be reasonable and overcome the presumption of immigration intent. But actually in this case I misremembered where Rochester is, so it may qualify as reasonable. Although I am not sure if C-1 appointments are more available than normal visitors.

Comment: @xngtng did anyone mention Rochester?  I figure they meant New York City because they "only need a day or two for the drive."  But depending on airfare or seat availability it's entirely possible that driving to NYC is reasonable from some parts of Canada.  It's about six hours from Kingston Ontario.